# Drupal 8 module routing page not found?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-8

I have a simple question, I want Drupal to route this page but keep getting this error:

```
"The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later."
```

The drupal error log displays this :

```
"InvalidArgumentException: Class "\Drupal\dblogin\Controller\DbloginController::reddb" does not exist. in Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ClassResolver->getInstanceFromDefinition() (line 24 of C:\drupal_sites\drupal-8.6.2\core\lib\Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ClassResolver.php)."
```

The code I have implemented for this is:

```
dblogin.reddb:
  path: /admin/reddb
  defaults:
    _title: 'DBlogin'
    _form: '\Drupal\dblogin\Controller\DbloginController::reddb'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

and in \src\Controller\DbloginController.php

```
<?php
namespace Drupal\dblogin\Controller;
use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

class dbloginController extends ControllerBase {

public function reddb() {
      $build = [
        '#markup' => $this->t('DB Login'),
      ];
      return $build;
}
/**
 * replacement process callbacks.
 */
}
?>
```

I have also tried to just make it return "hello", but to no avail.

```
<?php
namespace Drupal\dblogin\Controller;
use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

class dbloginController extends ControllerBase {

    public function reddb() {
        return "hello";
    }
    /**
       * replacement process callbacks.
    */
}
?>
```

Could anyone help me out here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, class `DbloginController` does not exisit, but class `dbloginController` does. Please note that class naming is **super important**. `DbloginController` and  `dbloginController` are two different classes. In your case change `_form: '\Drupal\dblogin\Controller\DbloginController::reddb'` to `_form: '\Drupal\dblogin\Controller\dbloginController::reddb'`. It should work after that.

Comment: Thanks for  your answer! I was trying different thing with my code and accidentally edited the name off the class to start with lower cases, see if that made a difference, I've reverted them all to start with upper cases now, but still get the same error, any idea why that might be?

Comment: Did you rebuild the menu cache ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

error:

```
_form: '\Drupal\dblogin\Controller\DbloginController::reddb'
```

It must be:

```
_controller: '\Drupal\dblogin\Controller\DbloginController::reddb'
```

Answer (score 0):

Name of class should same in routing and controller file. You should make changes in code like

```
<?php
namespace Drupal\dblogin\Controller;
use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

class DbloginController extends ControllerBase {

    public function reddb() {
        return "hello";
    }
    /**
       * replacement process callbacks.
    */
}
?>
```

in routing.

```
  requirements:
    _permission: 'administer site configuration'
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two Issues with your module which I can see from code.

1) In your routing file. Please replace your code with below lines.

```
dblogin.reddb:
  path: '/admin/reddb'
  defaults:
    _title: 'DBlogin'
    _form: '\Drupal\dblogin\Controller\DbloginController::reddb'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

2) In your controller. The file name and classname of your controller should be same everytime. So you controller code would be.

```
<?php
namespace Drupal\dblogin\Controller;
use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

class DbloginController extends ControllerBase {

public function reddb() {
      $build = [
        '#markup' => $this->t('DB Login'),
      ];
      return $build;
}
/**
 * replacement process callbacks.
 */
}
?>
```